# when I focus my input with border-radius , a square border appears out

Tags: html, css

when I focus my input with `border-radius`, a square border appears out.

Can i make this second border dispear or just set a `border radius` to it?

```css
input[type="text"]{
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

This is the square border:

[image: This is the square border]

Thanks.

Comment: Try to apply `outline="none"` to your `input[type="text"]` inside css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The blue rectangle is referenced as `outline` you can hide it via the `outline: none` rule

```css
input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius:10px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Of course you can style it.. See this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/outline) to see applicable rules.

---

*UPDATE*: In my answer I assumed that the question was about removing the outline of the HTML element to provide a custom one. As @Antifish made me notice this is a bad practice unless you don't provide alternative styles.

I looked up for some extra resources and found out someone made a [website about this](http://www.outlinenone.com) and it's clearly stated that:

> Defining focus to navigation elements is an accessibility requirement, it's clearly stated in the [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#navigation-mechanisms-focus-visible):
>
> > 2.4.7 Focus Visible: Any keyboard operable user interface has a mode of operation where the keyboard focus indicator is visible. (Level AA)

Comment: Thanks, nice answer :)

Comment: You can hide it, but it is bad practice to do so without providing a replacement style. The outline is there as an accessibility feature to allow keyboard users to see what element is currently focused.

Comment: @Antfish you're right it is a bad practice unless you provide a replacement style; which I supposed was what the question is about: hiding the regular outline to use a custom one.

Comment: @Antfish I've updated the answer adding some thought about what you said, thanks for letting me notice that I assumed something that shouldn't have been easily taken for granted.

Answer (score -2):

Just add `outline:none;` to your input.

```css
input[type="text"]{
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius:10px;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score -3):

Just add outline:0px none; to your input.

```
input[type="text"]{outline:0px none;}
```